# Number formatting in the table with spreadtab

Tags: tables, formatting, numbering, spreadtab

I am using `spreadtab` for the calculation in a table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{xstring}
\renewcommand\STprintnum[1]{\numprint{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \npthousandsep{,}
  \npdecimalsign{.}
  \nprounddigits{2}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{| l | l |r|}}   \hline
100000    & 120000    & b1-a1\\\hline
15        &  20       & b2-a2\\\hline
a1*a2/100 & b1*b2/100 & b2-b1\\\hline
\end{spreadtab}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And I got [image]. However, I want the second row to be `15.0` and `20.0` as percentage. How to change the number format settings while not affect other numbers?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @jarauh Thank you for note it out. I have added the code.

Comment: I have emailed `spreadtab` author and he replied me to try `fp` and `numprint` insteand of `spreadtab`. I think that is better way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading `numprint` with the option `autolanguage`. If the document does not use Babel, this will select the settings appropriate to English, which are those you seem to need. Don't use  `\npthousandsep` command then.

I don't know these things by heart, but `numprint` comes with documentation: `texdoc numprint`.